C# .NET based KiCAD parser
For internal evaluation I’m searching for a .NET based KiCAD parser that can read KiCAD PCB and schematic files. Has anyone experiences with those libraries?
For python I can find a lot but for .NET there seems to be nothing?

This parser could to fit your needs but seems to be an early development:
var parser = new EESchemaParser();
var parserResult = parser.Parse("myproject.kicad_sch");

if(parser.Success)
{
    var eeschema = parser.Result;
    var title = eeschema.TitleBlock.Title;
    
   //... 
}

and
var parser = new PcbNewParser();
var parserResult = parser.Parse("myproject.kicad_pcb");

if(parser.Success)
{
    var pcb = parser.Result;
    var title = pcb.TitleBlock.Title;
    
   //... 
}

and is available as nuget package:
dotnet add package MSDMarkwort.Kicad.Parser.PcbNew
dotnet add package MSDMarkwort.Kicad.Parser.EESchema

nice! this is quite new - will definitely have a look on that!
